# Strange Page Jump when clicking a JQuery Tab

Tags: jquery

I have uses some Jquery code for tabs on this page at the bottom:
http://isintl.com/certifications/tbc1/

However when the tabs are at the top of the page and clicked the page jumps down!

I have tried to implement a PREVENT DEFAULT but nothing works!

Please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// tabbed content
    // http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");


    });
    /* if in drawer mode */
    $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });


    /* Extra class "tab_last" 
       to add border to right side
       of last tab */
    $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the page is resizing itself to the size of the tab.  The first selected tab is taller that the second.  When you click on the tab, it take up less space that the first, putting less distance between the tabs and the bottom of the page.  The bottom of the page then snaps to the bottom of the window.

You can mitigate this by making your tabs all the same height with CSS.  This will add white space below some of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What Jeff Clarke said is actually correct, to prevent the page from jumping you could give your tab_container a min-height like so.

```
.tab_container {
  min-height: 900px;
}
```